# launching shortcuts

Tags: windows, shortcuts

By mistake,I have set the default program for .lnk files to windows media center.So whenever i launch a shortcut WMC opens but the shortcut does not get launched.Can you tell me what is the default programme to open shortcuts accurately?

Answer (score 2):

This will show you what your current association is. At a command prompt:

```
>assoc .lnk
.lnk=lnkfile
```

To return it to the value shown here:

```
>assoc .lnk=lnkfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Within Windows this is done by:

> 1. "Right-Click" on the program.
> 2. Select "Open With"
> 3. Select "Choose Default Program"
> 4. Select the program that you wish to associate with that file, and then select "ok"
> 5. The file should from then on be defaulted to the program you selected.

Comment: I thought it was quite clear from the fact that he's using "Windows Media Center", but I'll retag it to Windows.

Comment: @RandolphPotter Must've missed the WMC while reading it.  Answer still stays the same however.

Comment: Yup, which is why I didn't touch your answer :-)